# windows azure - event when role is destroyed

Tags: azure, lifecycle, azure-worker-roles

If i have a try/catch around the main loop in a worker role instance, will any exception be thrown when for example the worker role is taken down for an update/rebooted?

Is there another way to hook at "destroy" event, like a global try/catch handler or destructor? (for sure that is what is around any instance behind the scenes, so they can insulate the instances from the environment)

What are the overall life-cycle events for an worker/web role instance?

It is always said that Azure is a fail-proof and stable platform, but it is also said that an instance can go away any time. how to ensure that some 'critical' parts of code are not interrupted by the environment, and will complete uninterrupted.

Comment: is there something else youre looking for than what I answered?

Comment: So, at the end, the question stays: what if something (e.g. external COM component) throws `UnhandledException`. Is this handled somehow gracefully, and how? MSDN says `Stopping` is not fired at all. The idea is: Do i need to make the whole instance code, having in mind that it can be blown away any minute by some exception in some other thread in the role instance or who knows what? Is Azure taking care of that? How to write a handler that will handle 100% of the situations, not just 99.99%?

Answer (score 0):

When the role is being taken down in an ordered manner the `OnStop` method in your `workerrole.cs` file will be called;

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx)

```
public override void OnStop()
{
    try
    {
        // Add code here that runs when the role instance is to be stopped
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Exception during OnStop: " + e.ToString());
        // Take other action as needed.
    }
}
```

However I do think your try catch will be sufficient for any non-graceful issues. ;)

Comment: cool. I am not very familiar with he life-cycle of the instances. i was afraid that the environment can kill the process at any time, and imagining that some working threads are throwing exceptions of type "system is in shut-down state" or "thread is being aborted" - similar to when you shut-down your PC. it seems (according to the MSDN) that this will happen if you don't keep the 'OnStop' thread, until you finish the job.